# How to share data frames between scripts in R

Tags: r

I've got multiple R scripts; one that cleans my original data and produces a tidy data frame, and several others that performs functions on that data frame.

When I wrote them, the data frame produced by the first script was in my RStudio environment and the other scripts referenced the resulting data frame without trouble.

Now that I'm trying to run them from the console, the data frame produced by the first script isn't reference-able for the others.

What's the best way to share a data frame between scripts?

Comment: It sounds like the data frame had been stored in the R environment. Works in RStudio, but the console starts a new, empty environment for each script, so there’s no data to access. Save your data frame to a file and then load that file in subsequent scripts.

Comment: I would write a csv at the end of the first script and and read it as csv in the second. The fastest way to do that is `fwrite` and `fread` from package `data.table`

Comment: I would recommend `saveRDS()` and `readCSV()`.  Faster, smaller (compressed), no need serialize and de-serialize to text.

Comment: How about creating a script which runs all your scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the commands **save.image()** and **load()** to save your workspace to a file and then load it onto your console environment as it's likely that your console instance and RStudio each have their own independent environments.

Doing this way, you would have access to all objects that the previous scripts executed. However, if you're only interested in the generated data, you could save your data.frame using **save()** and open it using **load()**.

As mentioned by @Dirk Eddelbuettel, there are also plenty good functions to save single variables like **saveRDS()** and **readRDS()** (which provides a better serialization than save()) and **write.csv()** and **read.csv()**.

Comment: I would recommend saveRDS() and readCSV() for single variables. Easier to handle than the images, and more focussed.

Comment: Indeed, I had forgotten about both, will update answer accordingly.